# How to view documents stored in the AIR application in the browser?

Tags: apache-flex, browser, view, air

We have an AIR client which talks to a WAMP server. We store documents.
One of the customer requirement is: they want to their website users to view the documents stored in the AIR application. It should be a read only access. The users will not have our air client installed on their machines. All they do is to check the customer's website.
How can I implement this, please let me know.

Thanks
Vish.

Comment: What documents?  Word documents?  Spreadsheets?

Comment: Basically tiff images or pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to workout a system to send files to the server eventually store then in a Database. You can use a web service for both, sending files (base64encode -> send -> base64decode at destination) as well as running queries if needed.